# Get user Date in google-assistant app

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

I would like to get the date and time at the user location when they use my google-assistant app.

I could not find any ways to do that.

Comment: This would be useful for determining the user location https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484354/device-location-in-dialogflow-api-ai-webhook-request and then once you know the location of the user, you could use google time zone api to get the current time there https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro

Comment: I would like to find a different solution because I don't really need their location. I think it's a little bit awkward to ask a permission for something I don't need. But I guess this would work. If I don't find better I will use that. Thank you for your answer.