# How to access users location in Google assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am making a Chat-bot with Dialogflow as back end for Google Assistant. I want to access user's location and send it to server/cloud function to show more customized result. How can i implement it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Device location in dialogflow (api.ai) webhook request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484354/device-location-in-dialogflow-api-ai-webhook-request)

Answer (score 1):

The Below code works on devices with or without screen(Google Home).
Don't forget to add google map static key in your firebase config.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const maps = require('@google/maps');
const url = require('url');
const {
  dialogflow,
  Image,
  Permission,
  NewSurface,
} = require('actions-on-google');
const {ssml} = require('./util');

const config = functions.config();

const client = maps.createClient({key: config.maps.key});

const STATIC_MAPS_ADDRESS = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap';
const STATIC_MAPS_SIZE = '640x640';

const locationResponse = (city, speech) => {
  const staticMapsURL = url.parse(STATIC_MAPS_ADDRESS, true);
  staticMapsURL.query = {
    key: config.maps.key,
    size: STATIC_MAPS_SIZE,
  };
  staticMapsURL.query.center = city;
  const mapViewURL = url.format(staticMapsURL);
  return [
    speech,
    new Image({
      url: mapViewURL,
      alt: 'City Map',
    }),
  ];
};

const responses = {
  sayLocation: (city) => locationResponse(city, ssml`
    <speak>
      I am reading your mind now.
      <break time="2s"/>
      This is easy, you are in ${city}
      <break time="500ms"/>
      That is a beautiful town.
      <break time="500ms"/>
      Okay! I am off to read more minds.
    </speak>
  `),
  greetUser: ssml`
    <speak>
      Welcome to your Psychic!
      <break time="500ms"/>
      My mind is more powerful than you know.
      I wonder which of your secrets I shall unlock.
      Would you prefer I guess your location?
    </speak>
  `,
  unhandledDeepLinks: (input) => ssml`
    <speak>
      Welcome to your Psychic! I can guess many things about you,
      but I cannot make guesses about ${input}.
      Instead, I shall guess your location. Which do you prefer?
    </speak>
  `,
  readMindError: ssml`
    <speak>
      Wow!
      <break time="1s"/>
      This has never happened before. I cannot read your mind.
      I need more practice.
      Ask me again later.
    </speak>
  `,
  permissionReason: 'To read your mind',
  newSurfaceContext: 'To show you your location',
  notificationText: 'See you where you are...',
};

/**
   * Gets the city name from results returned by Google Maps reverse geocoding
   * from coordinates.
   * @param {number} latitude
   * @param {number} longitude
   * @return {Promise<string>}
   */
const coordinatesToCity = (latitude, longitude) => {
  const latlng = [latitude, longitude];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => client.reverseGeocode({latlng},
    (e, response) => {
      if (e) {
        return reject(e);
      }
      const {results} = response.json;
      const components = results[0].address_components;
      for (const component of components) {
        for (const type of component.types) {
          if (type === 'locality') {
            return resolve(component.long_name);
          }
        }
      }
      reject(new Error('Could not parse city name from Google Maps results'));
    })
  );
};

 /**
   * Shows the location of the user with a preference for a screen device.
   * If on a speaker device, asks to transfer dialog to a screen device.
   * Reads location from userStorage.
   * @param {object} conv - The conversation instance.
   * @return {Void}
   */
const showLocationOnScreen = (conv) => {
  const capability = 'actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT';
  if (conv.surface.capabilities.has(capability) ||
    !conv.available.surfaces.capabilities.has(capability)) {
    return conv.close(...responses.sayLocation(conv.user.storage.location));
  }
  conv.ask(new NewSurface({
    context: responses.newSurfaceContext,
    notification: responses.notificationText,
    capabilities: capability,
  }));
};

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  // conv.user.storage = {}
  // Uncomment above to delete the cached permissions on each request
  // to force the app to request new permissions from the user
  conv.ask(responses.greetUser);
});

app.intent('Unrecognized Deep Link Fallback', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(responses.unhandledDeepLinks(conv.query));
});

app.intent('request_location_permission', (conv) => {
  // If the request comes from a phone, we can't use coarse location.
  conv.data.requestedPermission =
    conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT')
    ? 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION'
    : 'DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION';
  if (!conv.user.storage.location) {
    return conv.ask(new Permission({
      context: responses.permissionReason,
      permissions: conv.data.requestedPermission,
    }));
  }
  showLocationOnScreen(conv);
});

app.intent('handle_permission', (conv, params, permissionGranted) => {
  if (!permissionGranted) {
    throw new Error('Permission not granted');
  }
  const {requestedPermission} = conv.data;

  if (requestedPermission === 'DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION') {
    // If we requested coarse location, it means that we're on a speaker device.
    conv.user.storage.location = conv.device.location.city;
    return showLocationOnScreen(conv);
  }
  if (requestedPermission === 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION') {
    // If we requested precise location, it means that we're on a phone.
    // Because we will get only latitude and longitude, we need to
    // reverse geocode to get the city.
    const {coordinates} = conv.device.location;
    return coordinatesToCity(coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude)
      .then((city) => {
        conv.user.storage.location = city;
        showLocationOnScreen(conv);
      });
  }
  throw new Error('Unrecognized permission');
});

app.intent('new_surface', (conv) => {
  conv.close(...responses.sayLocation(conv.user.storage.location));
});

app.catch((conv, e) => {
  console.error(e);
  conv.close(responses.readMindError);
});

exports.namePsychic = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: You should agree the code and not the liks that can be considered spam. Edit the Answer

Comment: This doesn't answer the user's question